# pkcs11 in python Thread

Tags: multiprocessing, ctypes, smartcard, pkcs#11, opensc

From within a single python thread, as shown below, I get the error "Please insert a token in any slot" and it seems to not see my token.  I change the code to not run from inside a multiprocessing Thread and it works.  To take the PyKCS11 library out of the equation I also tested by using ctypes and wrapping the standard pkcs11 functions implemented in opensc,  I still run into the same issue where it works except when run from a python Thread. What would cause this?

Using pkcs11 from inside a python Thread fails:

```
from PyKCS11 import LowLevel
import sys
from multiprocessing import Thread


class MyThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        lib = "/usr/local/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so" # place here your PKCS#11 library
        pin = "12345678" # place here the pin of your token

        a = LowLevel.CPKCS11Lib()
        info = LowLevel.CK_INFO()
        slotList = LowLevel.ckintlist()

        loadRes = a.Load(lib, 1)
        print "Load of library '%s' : %s " % (lib, str(loadRes) )
        if not loadRes: 
            sys.exit(1)
        print "C_GetInfo: rv=" , hex(a.C_GetInfo(info))
        print "Library manufacturerID: ", info.GetManufacturerID()
        # listing only slots with a token inside.
        rv = a.C_GetSlotList(1, slotList)
        if (rv != LowLevel.CKR_OK): 
            sys.exit(1)
        if len(slotList) == 0:
            print "Please insert a token in any slot"
            sys.exit(1)


mythread = MyThread()
mythread.start()
mythread.join()
```

Using pkcs11 outside of a Thread works:

```
from PyKCS11 import LowLevel
import sys

def run(self):
        lib = "/usr/local/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so" # place here your PKCS#11 library
        pin = "12345678" # place here the pin of your token

        a = LowLevel.CPKCS11Lib()
        info = LowLevel.CK_INFO()
        slotList = LowLevel.ckintlist()

        loadRes = a.Load(lib, 1)
        print "Load of library '%s' : %s " % (lib, str(loadRes) )
        if not loadRes: 
            sys.exit(1)
        print "C_GetInfo: rv=" , hex(a.C_GetInfo(info))
        print "Library manufacturerID: ", info.GetManufacturerID()
        # listing only slots with a token inside.
        rv = a.C_GetSlotList(1, slotList)
        if (rv != LowLevel.CKR_OK): 
            sys.exit(1)
        if len(slotList) == 0:
            print "Please insert a token in any slot"
            sys.exit(1)

run()
```

Testing Environment:

OS: OSX Yosemite

pkcs11 middleware: opensc

Answer (score 0):

More info about multi-threading and PKCS#11 libraries can be found in chapter 6.6.2 of PKCS#11 v2.20 specification:

> 6.6.2 Applications and threads
>
> Some applications will access a Cryptoki library in a multi-threaded
>   fashion. Cryptoki enables applications to provide information to
>   libraries so that they can give appropriate support for
>   multi-threading. In particular, when an application initializes a
>   Cryptoki library with a call to C_Initialize, it can specify one of
>   four possible multi-threading behaviors for the library:
>
> 1. The application can specify that it will not be accessing the library concurrently from multiple threads, and so the library need
>      not worry about performing any type of locking for the sake of
>      thread-safety.
> 2. The application can specify that it will be accessing the library concurrently from multiple threads, and the library must be able to
>      use native operation system synchronization primitives to ensure
>      proper thread-safe behavior.
> 3. The application can specify that it will be accessing the library concurrently from multiple threads, and the library must use a set of
>      application-supplied synchronization primitives to ensure proper
>      thread-safe behavior.
> 4. The application can specify that it will be accessing the library concurrently from multiple threads, and the library must use either
>      the native operation system synchronization primitives or a set of
>      application-supplied synchronization primitives to ensure proper
>      thread-safe behavior.

IMO the most commonly used type in multi-threaded apps is the 2nd type. To activate it you need to pass `CKF_OS_LOCKING_OK` flag to `C_Initialize` function. Following code shows how this can be achieved in C# with Pkcs11Interop library:

```cs
Pkcs11 pkcs11 = new Pkcs11(libraryPath);

CK_C_INITIALIZE_ARGS initArgs = new CK_C_INITIALIZE_ARGS();
initArgs.Flags = CKF.CKF_OS_LOCKING_OK;

CKR rv = pkcs11.C_Initialize(initArgs);
if ((rv != CKR.CKR_OK) && (rv != CKR.CKR_CRYPTOKI_ALREADY_INITIALIZED))
    throw new Pkcs11Exception("C_Initialize", rv);
```

I believe you need to use similar code in Python. Just guessing here but maybe you need to pass some parameter to `LowLevel.CPKCS11Lib()` ?